# Redirect links to correct directory

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, seo, joomla1.5, broken-links

We have on our site hundreds of links that point to:

```
/about/about/filename.html
```

But we need them to go to:

```
/about/filename.html
```

Is there a way to point them to the correct directory?

We are running on a Linux server and the site is build with Joomla Version 1.5.10 and there is ARTIO JoomSEF 3.8.2 running on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Apache webserver, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), specifically the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive:

```
RewriteRule /about/about/(.+)$ /about/$1 [R=301]
```

Place this rule in your `httpd.conf` file in the `<VirtualHost>` context for the site in question, or in a `.htaccess` file in the site's DocumentRoot.

This rule will create a 301 Permanent redirect for requests to any path under `/about/about/` to the same path under `/about/`. e.g., `/about/about/filename.html` will redirect to `/about/filename.html`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work i have a feeling that the JoomSEF is causing the conflict.